# getting recent message of the user

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, message

What I'm trying to do is select the recent message from what a user sends me.

For example there are two users:

- Richard
- Paul

*Richard* sends me three messages:

1. hi
2. how are you doing?
3. Whats up?

*Paul* sends me one message:

1. hi

How do I show what *Richard's* **RECENT** message was to me instead of all three messages and then show *Paul's* one message (obviously they are ordered by the time sent).

This is what i've got...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `private_messages` WHERE `to_id`='$session_user_id' AND `id`=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM `private_messages`) ORDER BY `time_sent` DESC") or die("Error.");
```

This only shows the first message which is the max `id`, how do I solve it? :( thanks.

Comment: Take out the sub select, have no idea why it is there, and add a `from_uid` field to your schema and use that to filter only two messages out from Rich instead of the one from Paul as well, done

Comment: I highly recommend switching to mysqli from mysql, which is deprecated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to display the last message by every person that has sent you one or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to display only the last message sent to you by everyone...

To do that, you can use a derived table and join the two together.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS message_id
        FROM private_messages
        WHERE to_id='$session_user_id'
        GROUP BY sender_id
    ) msg_ids
JOIN private_messages ON msg_ids.message_id = private_messages.id
ORDER BY time_sent DESC;
```

I'd give this query a try.
Make sure you change the field name 'sender_id' in the GROUP BY-clause to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which will select the most recent message with `to_id` equal to `$session_user_id`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `private_messages` WHERE `to_id`='$session_user_id' ORDER BY `time_sent` DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
mysqli_query($query) or die("Error.");
```

Ideally, you'd add a column `from_id` so that you can filter out only the messages between the two people in question:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `private_messages` WHERE (`to_id`='$session_user_id' AND `from_id`=[FROM_ID_GOES_HERE_]) ORDER BY `time_sent` DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
mysqli_query($query) or die("Error.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers except this will also only get two of the three messages due to filtering the from user.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `private_messages` WHERE `to_id`='$session_user_id' AND from_id='rich_uid' ORDER BY `time_sent` DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
mysqli_query($query) or die("Error.");
```

### Edit

To use this query you will need to understand Rich's User ID which is his "`$session_user_id`" and place a new field of your choice (shown here as `from_id`) to the schema of this table and use that to filter on Rich's ID.